# What is the keyboard shortcut to select multiple regions in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working with vscode and don't know is there any way to select multiple regions in vscode?
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold `Alt` + `left mouse button` to highlight the areas you want to select.

[image]

Comment: @Someone in the settings you can change the Multi Cursor key (`Alt` key)